# Confused about emplace_back of std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

I was trying to understand the emplace_back method hoping it have performance gain.

For a simple class:

```
class Widget {
public:
  Widget(Widget&& w) {
    cout << "moving widget" << endl;
  }
  Widget(const Widget& w) {
    cout << "copying widget" << endl;
  }
  Widget() {
    cout << "constructing widget" << endl;
  }

  const Widget operator=(const Widget &w) {
    cout << "copy assign widget" << endl;
    return *this;
  }

  Widget operator=(Widget &&w) {
    cout << "move assign widget" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
  string name = "hello";
};
```

and used like this:

```
  vector<Widget> v { {Widget(), Widget(), Widget()} }; // 3 copy
  cout << "-------" << endl;
  vector<Widget> v2;
  v2.emplace_back();
  v2.emplace_back();
  v2.emplace_back(); // why still copying?
  cout << "-------" << endl;
```

have output:

```
constructing widget
constructing widget
constructing widget
copying widget
copying widget
copying widget
-------
constructing widget
constructing widget
copying widget
constructing widget
copying widget
copying widget
-------
```

1. I thought emplace back would construct the Widget "in place" without the need to copy?
2. Why constructing and copying of emplace_back is neither in pairs nor grouped together?

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing here is the effect of the vector internally growing and copying your elements.

If your move constructors/operators would be noexcept it would move them instead.